# how to customize react-native-date-picker value to 'yyyy'-'mm'-'dd' format

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I'm using `react-native-date-picker` package to get date input. I'm using this code to get value.

I'm using `Date()` type for date variable

```
this.state = {
    date :new Date()
}
```

I'm passing this as json object and date pick by this code

```
<DatePicker
  date={this.state.date}
  mode = {'date'}
  onDateChange={date => this.setState({date})}
/>
```

from this i get output like this.  `Sun Dec 23 2018 16:11:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` but i need to get it like `2018-12-23` how to format it like this.

[image]

How to format date to 'yyyy'-'mm'-'dd' format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

produce formatted string from Date object

```js
date = new Date()//return today

formattedDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate()

console.log(formattedDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Date` offers your the [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) function, which returns a string of the date with the following format: `2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z`.
You can then just extract the yyyy-mm-dd formatted date from the string like this:

```
date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

But be careful, because this method converts the date to UTC time first. That means, if you're in another timezone your date might be shift to another day due the time offset. To prevent this, you can try out:

```
const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
date = new Date(date.getTime() + (offset*60*1000));
date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 1):

**import moment** and add the following lines

```
moment(date).format("YYYY MM DD")
```

Answer (score 0):

Set locale to 'en'
I've used with package on this works perfectly.